# Writing $ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\frac{m}{m-i}} =\frac{m}{n}\left( H_n-H_{m-n} \right) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, harmonic-numbers

Given the following series, where $m,n$ are integers such that $n<m$:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\frac{m}{m-i}}\\
=\frac{m}{n}\left( H_n-H_{m-n} \right) 
\end{align}

We know that harmonic number $H_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + + \frac{1}{n}$. So,

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\frac{m}{m-i}}\\
=\frac{m}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{m-i}}\\
=\frac{m}{n}(\frac{1}{m-0}+\frac{1}{m-1}+\frac{1}{m-2}+\cdots \frac{1}{(m-n)+1})\\
\end{align}

So,
\begin{align}
H_n=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots \frac{1}{n}\\
H_{m-n}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots \frac{1}{m-n}\\
\end{align}

Since $m>n$, how we can guarantee as well that $H_n - H_{m-n}$ is positive please? So, I see that difference here $H_n - H_{m-n} > 0$.

**Problem 1**: How we can proceed please to derive $\frac{m}{n}\left( H_n-H_{m-n} \right)$?

**Edit**: I made a mistake as it's $H_m - H_{m-n}$.

Comment: Are you stuck at intuitive understanding or rigorous manipulation?

Comment: @Trebor. Thanks for the reply. I am just looking to get the difference of two harmonic numbers above $(H_n−H_{m−n})$. Any effort you can put is appreciated.

Comment: Stop using Sigmas and expand $H_n$, then you will see it intuitively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We obtain for positive integers $m>n$
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{m}{m-i}}
> &=\frac{m}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m-i}\\
> &=\frac{m}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m-(n-1-i)}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{m}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m-n+1+i}\\
> &=\frac{m}{n}\sum_{i=m-n+1}^m\frac{1}{i}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{m}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{m-n}\frac{1}{i}\right)\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{m}{n}\left(H_m-H_{m-n}\right)}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we change the order of summation: $i\to n-1-i$.
- In (2) we shift the index and start with $i=m-n+1$. To compensate this shift we substitute $i$ with $i-m+n-1$ within the scope of the sum.
- In (3) we write the sum as difference of *[Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)*.

Comment: Thank you very much. In (1), you did not change $i$ in the summation though please?

Comment: @Avra: You're welcome! :-)  In (1) we have $a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_{n-1-i}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+\cdots+a_0$.